# How to fix 'ImportError' while working with multiple Django apps

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-packaging

I'm working with multiple apps in django and facing **ImportError** while running `makemigrations` command. 
 The import statements are as follows, appwise:

**accounting/models.py**
    `from activity.models import HistoryModel`

**activity/models.py**
`from user_management.models import Customer, Merchant, PassIssued`
`from accounting.models import ITMSCustomer`

**user_management/models.py**
`from accounting.models import Account, Transaction, Posting`

I'm sure that the order of apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS matter and the order is:

```
'user_management',
'accounting',
'activity',
```

I get following error when I run `makemigrations` command:

```
  File "/home/abhishek/citycash/city-server/src/cityserver/user_management/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from accounting.models import Account, Transaction, Posting
  File "/home/abhishek/citycash/city-server/src/cityserver/accounting/models.py", line 17, in <module>
    from activity.models import HistoryModel
  File "/home/abhishek/citycash/city-server/src/cityserver/activity/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from user_management.models import Customer, Merchant, PassIssued
ImportError: cannot import name 'Customer'
```

I tried changing the order of apps in INSTALLED_APPS but I just ended up getting ImportError for different modules. I know this has something to do with the fact that all three apps are importing something from each other. How do I resolve this error? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you performing circular imports in the files or using wild char import like: test.models import *     ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but yes I'm not performing imports using * anywhere. All the imports are specific, like: from app.models import ModelName.

Comment: Try using [lazy relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) on your ForeignKey fields. Instead of `models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` you'd use `models.ForeignKey('user_management.Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and remove related import.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This would help me resolve the ImportError but I still can't remove the Imports that I'm currently performing. Because in case I need to filter or get the the records of these models, they need to be imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help someone in future facing the same problem, I finally ended up creating a new app (to have `HistoryModel`, `BaseHistoryModel`, etc.) and import it. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass
```

To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly specify a model with the full application label. For example, if the Manufacturer model above is defined in another application called production, you’d need to use:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'production.Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

This sort of reference, called a lazy relationship, can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies between two applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned in the other comment, I cannot remove the imports (which is I guess is the main cause of issue), as I have to perform 'filter' and 'get' on those Models further in the same modules.